# How to validate the text value of an element

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests

My question is when i insert a text in an element, how can i know if an element received the right text, i tried something like this :

```
IWebElement BreveDEscricao = Gdriver.FindElement(By.Id("descricao_breve"));
BreveDEscricao.SendKeys("Alfa Romeo 4c Spider ");

IWebElement descricao = Gdriver.FindElement(By.Id("descricao"));
descricao.SendKeys("A primeira vez que vir um 4C Spider, dirá 'o céu é o limite'. Esta obra-prima de estilo e performances nasceu a partir do mais puro espírito Alfa Romeo: um projeto que pretende exibir com entusiasmo um supercarro de sonho. Um automóvel único, criado para conquistar o condutor, tanto em pista como em estrada. Finalmente, o sonho de todos os apaixonados por automóveis pode ser concretizado.");
IWebElement ModalidadeDaVenda = Gdriver.FindElement(By.Id("modalidade_venda"));
ModalidadeDaVenda.SendKeys("Leilão Online");
IWebElement Ano = Gdriver.FindElement(By.Id("ano"));
Ano.SendKeys("2016");
Gdriver.ExecuteJavaScript("document.getElementById('penhora').checked = true");
try
{
    BreveDEscricao.GetAttribute("Text");
    descricao.GetAttribute("A primeira vez que vir um 4C Spider, dirá 'o céu é o limite'.Esta obra - prima de estilo e performances nasceu a partir do mais puro espírito Alfa Romeo: um projeto que pretende exibir com entusiasmo um supercarro de sonho.Um automóvel único, criado para conquistar o condutor, tanto em pista como em estrada. Finalmente, o sonho de todos os apaixonados por automóveis pode ser concretizado.");
    ModalidadeDaVenda.GetAttribute("Leilão Online");
    Ano.GetAttribute("2016");
    MessageBox.Show("Information inserted successful", "Dados",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
catch(Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Information insertes doesn't the values in the  site", "Dados", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

So my question is how i can validate the text i inserted?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your question.  What's wrong with what you've tried?  Do you get an error?  what is it?  What do you mean by "validate the text I inserted"?  do you want to check that the field has the value that SendKeys() sent, or are you really interested in checking that the site behaves as you expect once you have entered some text?

Comment: what i doing now is something like this  if (someelement.Text == "my string ") ), but what happens is, i get a null text, so i think the problem is that the site runs a lot of JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are talking about input HTML element, when you set a text it goes into value attribute. so you can simply get that attribute and verify again.

Something like this

```
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://google.com");
    WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    searchBox.sendKeys("selenium");
    String value = searchBox.getAttribute("value");
    System.out.print(value);
    driver.quit();
```

Comment: Nice, but as you know that would take lot of effort, i have much more elements than that and i m running an Automatism, i need use a function or something like so to do it.

Comment: so what is stopping you to create a function and calling it for each element you have?

Comment: @PedroAlvim Why in the world do you need a function for a one-liner, `element.getAttribute("value")`? You already have to touch each element to put text into it... just add the one line to validate and you are done.